# Calling REST service with domain credentials from .NET 4.5 HttpClient

Tags: c#, rest, active-directory, .net-4.5

I want to call a REST service that requires domain authentication from .NET 4.5. (*Using Visual Studio 2012*)

Searching Google leads to lots of links of people saying that HttpClient is now the way to do this.

However as far as I can tell there is no way to impersonate or attach credentials to HttpClient.

In addition, all the popular REST libraries seem to not be compatible with .NET 4.5 yet.

Over [StackOverflow posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212116/how-to-get-httpclient-to-pass-credentials-along-with-the-request) have suggested WebClient as a way around this, although this seems no longer available in .NET 4.5.

If I want to call a REST service with domain credentials from a .NET 4.5 client, what is the best method?

Comment: It seems like it is complicated researching HttpClient, since it has gone through a long beta cycle and changed a lot before becoming part of .Net 4.5. Short answer is that this is simple: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/35e2a7ae-bba0-406a-a10e-f1677dd5a471/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HttpClient in .NET 4.5 does support domain authentication. You need to insert a HttpClientHandler with the 'UseDefaultCredentials' setting set to true:

```
        string searchResults = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);

            client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 100000;
            string responseString = await client.GetStringAsync(RestServiceUrl);

            searchResults = responseString;
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException e)
        {
            searchResults = e.Message;
        }
```

Also it is worth noting that if you are building a Windows 8 application then you need to enable 'Enterprise Authentication' in the Package.appManifest:

[image]