# How do I add windows authentification to my web service

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wcf, rest

I have WCF Service, my goal is to be able to retrieve information from my server using GET and POST. I almost got it to work. My problem is that to be able to access the information on the server I need to enter my credentials, otherwise I get the error 401 unauthorized

I tried a few different things but I'm still new at using XML and when I try to add some code I always get errors.

This is my code:

C#

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IRestServiceImpl
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "xml/{id}")]
        string XMLData(string id);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "json/{id}")]
        string JSONData(string id);
    }
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="RestService.RestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address ="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="RestService.IRestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="web">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

I still don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Google: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=434

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft Thank you for your answer. Could you help me get the XML to work, if I copy it I get over 30 errors. Expecting end tag, Missing attribute name, Tag was not closed.

Comment: There is lacking som spaces in the xml configuration.

Comment: I got it to run but I get an error. See updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (link to code download below listing):

```
// IRestService.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace RestService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IRestServiceImpl
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "xml/{id}")]
        string XMLData(string id);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "json/{id}")]
        string JSONData(string id);
    }
}

// RestService.cs
namespace RestService
{
    public class RestServiceImpl : IRestServiceImpl
    {
        public string JSONData(string id)
        {
            return id;
        }

        public string XMLData(string id)
        {
            return id;
        }
    }
}


<!-- RestService.svc (Source) -->
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="RestService.RestServiceImpl" CodeBehind="RestService.svc.cs"
    Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" %>

<!--  Web.config -->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="RestService.RestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"  bindingConfiguration="webBinding" contract="RestService.IRestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="web">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webBinding">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="Windows">
            </transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <windowsAuthentication allowAnonymousLogons="false" includeWindowsGroups="true" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Results below (your base URL will likely differ). Ignore the "Endpoint not found" message you see. Rest services should not expose metadata (unless HATEOAS is considered metadata in your mind :)

http://localhost:62001/RestService.svc/xml/absee

```
<XMLDataResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<XMLDataResult>absee</XMLDataResult>
</XMLDataResponse>
```

http://localhost:62001/RestService.svc/json/absee

```
{"JSONDataResult":"absee"}
```

[Download the code here](http://1drv.ms/1QfR7hC)

You may want to set it to run under IIS Express in the project settings under the Web tab.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I don't understand the last part. What is this: `<XMLDataResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<XMLDataResult>absee</XMLDataResult>
</XMLDataResponse>` ? I tried to copy the code but it seems like I still get an error 401. I can't download your project because I'm using visual studio 2010

Comment: Hi Phil, that XML is a sample output from the code you provided. See your original post under "This is my code".  In terms of the code, it should work on 2010 with a bit of backporting. try creating a new blank WCF service and solution of the same name and copying the code in.

Comment: For the 401, this is a sign that authentication is working. Http 401: The Web server (running the Web site) thinks that the HTTP data stream sent by the client (e.g. your Web browser or our CheckUpDown robot) was correct, but access to the URL resource requires user authentication. If you are running under IIS, make sure that the connecting service has the correct credentials. Use chrome debug tools or fiddler http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: Is it possible to ask for credentials then launch the web service and use those credentials?

Comment: You would want to set the credentials before the call to the web  service, not as a challenge-response like a web site would behave. Here is what I think you are after: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15434779/calling-rest-service-with-domain-credentials-from-net-4-5-httpclient