# Impersonation inside SQL CLR while consumnig WebAPI

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, impersonation, sqlclr

I have problem with impersonation inside SQL CLR. I work on .NET 4.5, SQL Server 2012.

I have a WebAPI service on http://webapitest.example.com/ which have windows authentication enabled and expose a method FileUpload (POST). This is simple method which takes file and store it in SQL Server database. Service is hosted by IIS (7.5, Windows 2008R2) which is running on dedicated account DOMAIN\X.

When I call this service using Fiddler every works great. Service store file in DB as current windows user.

My problems occurs when I try to consume this webAPI method inside SQL CLR Procedure (code below). CLR procedure is running in SQL Server account context (DOMAIN\SQL), so I impersonate inside procedure to user from SqlContext.

```
[SqlProcedure]
public static void UploadBinaryContent([SqlFacet(MaxSize = -1)] byte[] vBytes, string serviceUrl)
{
    WindowsIdentity clientId = null;
    WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = null;
    clientId = SqlContext.WindowsIdentity;
    impersonatedUser = clientId.Impersonate();

    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        UseDefaultCredentials = true
    };

    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(vBytes);
            fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = "Foo.txt"
            };
            content.Add(fileContent);

            string requestUri = serviceUrl;

            try
            {

                if (impersonatedUser != null)
                {
                    // this works as impersonated user ...
                    conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SERVER; Initial Catalog=WebAPITest;Trusted_Connection=True;");
                    conn.Open();
                    command = conn.CreateCommand();
                    command.CommandText = "SELECT 2";
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    command.ExecuteReader();
                    conn.Close();

                    // but this service is called by SQL Sever account
                    var httpResponseMessage = client.PostAsync(requestUri, content).Result;

                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (impersonatedUser != null)
                {
                    impersonatedUser.Undo();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that despite of impersonation WebAPI service try to put file into DB as DOMAIN\SQL. Interestingly calling direct SQL command is running on impersonated user.

The question is how can I consume WebAPI service POST method inside SQL CLR procedure as impersonated user?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get HttpClient to pass credentials along with the request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212116/how-to-get-httpclient-to-pass-credentials-along-with-the-request)