# Web API Call from a C# console application with credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to write a Web API site with a Get method that is Authorized. The site is a default template site, using Individual Accounts. So it stores the username and password in a database. I am attempting to call this Web API site and pass along a username and password in a console application via HttpClient. I have tried several ways of going about this. I think* i have CORS enabled on my API site. I keep getting Unauthorized results. Here is the HttpClient code I am running, I feel like it is completely valid, and I think something needs to be configured to handle this username and password on the API side, but I am completely unsure how to go about it if that is the case.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("sampleUser:Test123!");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:15198/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    try
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/Query");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            thing = response.Content.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException e)
    {
        var test = e.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Couple of comments: CORS only comes into play if you are making this request from *javascript* - since the console app is making the request, CORS shouldn't be a concern. Secondly, I hope you will move to **https** once this is in production - as you are essentially sending the password in cleartext (base64 encoded cleartext)

Comment: Also, can you post a bit of the ApiController (and potentially the routing configuration you are using)?

Comment: Without seeing your API code, there's not much to go on. Perhaps this page might give you some pointers? http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api

Comment: Its just a default web api project, i used individual account authentication, thats really it. Thats why I didnt bother posting that code. I find examples of passing username password, but cant find anything as far as how to set up the API side.

Comment: The challenge is that "individual account authentication" doesn't really tell us how the auth process is supposed to work.  With the 401 Unauthorized response, there should be a www-authenticate header that tells you what security scheme the server is expecting you do use.  Does it say "basic" ?

Comment: And as a side note, response.Content.ToString(); will not do what you expect.  You need to do something like await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()

Answer (score 0):

you would need to impersonate and pass the credentials assuming your running windows authentication on your server.

```
  using (new Impersonator(UserName, Domain, Pwd))
         {
            ...http request
         }
```

See [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37858687/how-to-pass-impersonated-user-in-web-api-call-from-console-app-with-windows-auth)