# HttpRequestMessage with Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-authentication

I'm trying to do some integration testing on an ASP.Net Core app with Windows Authentication enabled. For controller methods with the [Authorize] attribute I need to send through the current windows identity in the request.

There is lots of information on how to do this using the old HttpWebRequest method, but I can find no information on doing this through HttpRequestMessage. Presumably I have to encode and send through the current user in the authentication header? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asp.Net Core does not do impersonation for you. You need to call WindowsIdentity.Impersonate (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka(v=vs.110).aspx) to apply the given identity to the current thread. Then you set up HttpClient with UseDefaultCredentials: [How to get HttpClient to pass credentials along with the request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212116/how-to-get-httpclient-to-pass-credentials-along-with-the-request)