# Why am I not getting my username in the windows authenticated Web Core API?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

This code in my Web Core API confirms that I am an authenticated user, but I am not getting my username, instead I am getting the name of the application pool.
How do I fix this?

```
var testa = User.Identity.GetType();
NLogger.Info($"testa = {testa}");
var testd = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
NLogger.Info($"testd = {testd}");
var loggedInUser = User.Identity.Name;
NLogger.Info($"loggedInUser = {loggedInUser}");
```

In my logfile I get;

```
testa = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity
testd = True
loggedInUser = IIS APPPOOL\SIR.WEBUI
```

I use the [Authorize] tag for the controller and anonymous authentication is disabled.

Well I call the method from Postman, it works OK, the LoggedInUser is correct. But when I call from my code I get the incorrect loggedInUser shown above.
The code I use to call the web api from my client app is;

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<ContractDto>> GetAllForUser()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = true }))
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(AppSettings.ServerPathApi);
        var path = GetPath("getallforuser");
        var response = await client.GetAsync(path);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var stringResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<ContractDto>>(stringResult);
    }
}
```

In IIS I have set the application pool type to all of the various options;
applicationpoolidentity, networkservice, localservice, localsystem and tested the application each time. What on earth am I missing?

Comment: An accept answer to a similar issue here https://stackoverflow.com/a/12675503/5233410

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem, but I suggest you try setting "Load User Profile" to true, if not already, in  IIS

Comment: @Nkosi, tried that but it does not work. I am using Web Core API and I think impersonation works differently. Maybe I should be using impersonation? But then I do not need to do so when using AJAX, so why should C# be any different?

Comment: have you tried  userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
  string username = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
}
```

or you can try

```
var user = (System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
var userName = user.Impersonate();
```

Comment: Having done some research, I found out that a call from AJAX will take my identity from the browser, but via IIS it will take the application pool instead. The solution for IIS is to use impersonation and I am looking into that now.

Comment: @arame3333 if you want to add impersonation use the second code but add this part var userName = user.Impersonate(). i have edited the answer to include it

Comment: @arame3333 you can check this link there is a similar question here [Get Credentials with Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212116/how-to-get-httpclient-to-pass-credentials-along-with-the-request/12675503#12675503)

Comment: impersonation has to be setup in the calling code before the request is made so that code can work in the Web Core API. I need to find out how to do that.