# HttpClient, UseDefaultCredentials, Windows Authentication, .NET Core 2.0+ console application receives 401 Unauthorized

Tags: .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to make an HTTP GET call from a .NET Core 3.0 console application. The endpoint expects Windows Authentication. The endpoint is an in-production .NET Framework 4.5.2 Web API service on IIS successfully used by several client applications.

My test program succeeds for a `net45` framework target. In contrast, the `netcoreapp3.0` build receives a 401 Unauthorized.

Here is my method:

```cs
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

static async Task<string> Get(string serverUri, string requestUri)
{
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true };
    var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = new Uri(serverUri) };
    return await client.GetStringAsync(requestUri);
}
```

Here is my project file.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworks>net45;netcoreapp3.0</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net45'">
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http" Version="4.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Running `.\bin\Debug\net45\HttpClientTest.exe` returns the expected JSON result.

Running `dotnet .\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\HttpClientTest.dll` receives a 401 Unauthorized.

```
Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).)
    ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
    at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GetStringAsyncCore(Task`1 getTask)
    at ConsoleApp1.Program.Get(String serverUri, String requestUri) in C:\temp\coreapp3\Program.cs:line 16
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
    at ConsoleApp1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\temp\coreapp3\Program.cs:line 22
```

**How do I fix this?**

I have also tried the variations below, without any change in output:

```cs
handler.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
handler.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
handler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get HttpClient to pass credentials along with the request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212116/how-to-get-httpclient-to-pass-credentials-along-with-the-request)

Comment: I continue to run into this issue. I'm now on .NET Core 2.2.

Comment: For the record, I tried this solution suggested as a possible duplicate... https://stackoverflow.com/a/48649925/167920 ... without success.

Comment: Try it in newest version of netcoreapp.

Comment: @pavinan I re-ran my experiment with .NET Core 3.0. Same result. For .NET 4.5, works fine. For .NET Core 3.0, I get a 401 Unauthorized.

Comment: Check here you may find something, https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/25988

Comment: @WallaceKelly - were you able to resolve this issue? We are running into same with .Net core 2.2 trying to call .Net 4.7 app on same application in IIS.

Comment: @ShivaNaru I have not seen a solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

This workaround works for me add this before creating HttpClient / Handler:

```
AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.UseSocketsHttpHandler", false);
```

Comment: This setting was removed in .NET 5.  See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/run-time-config/networking

Answer (score -1):

So we are running into the same issue with HttpClient, but on the first request it is unauthorized, but if we do a another quick request call, it goes through just fine, and we get authorized.

If I do this on a .NET 4.7.1 console app, it works perfect.  If I do it in a .NET 4.7.1 empty web app, it works fine, only if I do .NET Core 2.x do we get this issue.

```
var result = string.Empty;
var responseMessage = _client.GetAsync(url).Result;

if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    result = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
else
{
    var responseMessage2 = _client.GetAsync(url).Result;

    if (responseMessage2.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        result = await responseMessage2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}

return result;
```