# EWS. The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized on Mac OS only

Tags: c#, .net, macos, .net-core, exchangewebservices

I need to connect to EWS. I am using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.NETStandard NuGet package for that. On the Windows machine everything is ok, but on Mac OS I'm getting the error "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized." Also, if I use just Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices it works fine, but whole my project is based on .Net Core. Maybe, somebody has encountered this problem.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;

namespace testExchange
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var exchangeService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2, TimeZoneInfo.Utc);
            
            string userLogin = "userLogin";
            string userPass = "userPassword";
            string exchangeDomain = "icx";
            string userEmail = "userEmail@domain.com";
            string webmail = "https://domain/ews/Exchange.asmx";
            exchangeService.Credentials = new WebCredentials(userLogin, userPass, exchangeDomain);
            exchangeService.Url = new Uri(webmail);

            string name = exchangeService.ResolveName(userEmail, ResolveNameSearchLocation.DirectoryOnly, true).Result.First().Contact.DisplayName;

            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.UseSocketsHttpHandler", false);
```

It helped. Just add this.
Thanks so much to [Ahh Bui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2086576/anh-bui)

[Post where I found the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46306508/httpclient-usedefaultcredentials-windows-authentication-net-core-2-0-consol/62208415#62208415)