# 'WebRequest.Create(string)' is obsolete: 'WebRequest, Use HttpClient instead.'

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, httpclient, webrequest

I upgraded my .NET application from the version NET5 to NET6 and placed with a warning that the WebRequest class was obsolete. I've looked at a few examples online, but using HttpClient doesn't automatically grab credentials like WebRequest does, as you need to insert them into a string manually.

How would I convert this using the HttpClient class or similar?

```
 string url = "website.com";
        WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create(url);
        wr.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        HttpWebResponse hwr = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new(hwr.GetResponseStream());
        
    
        sr.Close();
        hwr.Close();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

```
var myClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true });
var response = await myClient.GetAsync("website.com");
var streamResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
```

more info around credentials: [How to get HttpClient to pass credentials along with the request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212116/how-to-get-httpclient-to-pass-credentials-along-with-the-request)

Comment: And then read [You're using HttpClient wrong and it is destabilizing your software](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) followed by [You're (probably still) using HttpClient wrong and it is destabilizing your software](https://josef.codes/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/)