# Is delegation required to pass credentials between applications on the SAME server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API application and an MVC4 client application on the **same** web server. They are both configured for Windows Authentication. The client application has impersonation enabled.

When I run the client in Visual Studio, it successfully passes my windows credentials to the Web API.

When I hit the client on the web server, the Web API receives "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" which I guess is coming from the application pool the client app is running in.

Client passes credentials as follows:

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    PreAuthenticate = true,
    UseDefaultCredentials = true
};
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

So my question is...do I need delegation here?

The web server is not configured for this in Active Directory - but I thought as the applications are on the same server, that impersonation would be sufficient. I would turn delegation on but I need a system admin to do that - and have all sorts of hoops to jump through - so want to be sure that's what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, in short, no - delegation was not required.

It turned out to be an **impersonation** issue. From what I'd read it sounded like that was what should be required since the applications are on the same server, but even though I thought I had configured it correctly, I was missing a crucial part. I needed to change two settings in aspnet.config:

```
<legacyImpersonationPolicy enabled="false"/>
<alwaysFlowImpersonationPolicy enabled="true"/>
```

More details here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10311823/1230905