# HttpClient & Windows Auth: Pass logged in User of Consumer to Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I am struggling to understand and set up a Service and Consumer where the Service will run as the user logged into the Consumer.

My consumer is an MVC application. My Service is a Web Api application. Both run on separate servers within the same domain. Both are set to use Windows Auth.

My consumer code is:

```
private T GenericGet<T>(string p)
    {
        T result = default(T);

        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler() { PreAuthenticate = true, UseDefaultCredentials = true };
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(serviceEndPoint);

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(p).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>().Result;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

In my Service I call `User.Identity.Name` to get the caller ID but this always comes back as the consumer App Pool ID, not the logged in user. The consumer App Pool is running as a Network Service, the server itself is trusted for delegation. So how do I get the logged in User? Service code:

```
    // GET: /Modules/5/Permissions/
    [Authorize]
    public ModulePermissionsDTO Get(int ModuleID)
    {
        Module module= moduleRepository.Find(ModuleID);
        if (module== null)
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

        // This just shows as the App Pool the MVC consumer is running as (Network Service).
        IPrincipal loggedInUser = User;

        // Do I need to do something with this instead?
        string authHeader = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

        ModulePermissionsDTO dto = new ModulePermissionsDTO();
        // Construct object here based on User...

        return dto;
    }
```

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212116/how-to-get-httpclient-to-pass-credentials-along-with-the-request?lq=1), Kerberos is required to make this set up work because the HttpClient runs in a separate thread. However this confuses me because I thought the request sends an Authorization header and so the service should be able to use this and retrieve the user token. Anyway, I have done some testing with Kerberos to check that this correctly works on my domain using the demo in "Situation 5" [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/canberrapfe/archive/2012/01/02/kerberos-troubleshooting.aspx) and this works but my two applications still wont correctly pass the logged in user across.

So what do I need to do to make this work? Is Kerberos needed or do I need to do something in my Service to unpack the Authorisation header and create a principal object from the token? All advice appreciated.

Comment: HttpClientHandler implements IDisposable. So shouldn't that be wrapped in a 'using' construct also?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The key is to let your MVC application (consumer) impersonate the calling user and then issue the HTTP requests synchronously (i.e. without spawning a new thread). You should not have to concern yourself with low-level implementation details, such as NTLM vs Kerberos.

## Consumer

Configure your MVC application like so:

1. Start IIS Manager
2. Select your MVC web application
3. Double click on 'Authentication'
4. **Enable** 'ASP.NET Impersonation'
5. **Enable** 'Windows Authentication'
6. **Disable** other forms of authentication (unless perhaps Digest if you need it)
7. Open the Web.config file in the root of your MVC application and ensure that `<authentication mode="Windows" />`

To issue the HTTP request, I recommend you use the excellent [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) library. Example:

```
var client = new RestClient("<your base url here>");
client.Authenticator = new NtlmAuthenticator();
var request = new RestRequest("Modules/5/Permissions", Method.GET);
var response = client.Execute<ModulePermissionsDTO>(request);
```

## Service

Configure your Web API service like so:

1. Start IIS Manager
2. Select your Web API service
3. Double click on 'Authentication'
4. **Disable** 'ASP.NET Impersonation'.
5. **Enable** 'Windows Authentication'
6. If only a subset of your Web API methods requires users to be authenticated, leave 'Anonymous Authentication' enabled.
7. Open the Web.config file in the root of your Web API service and ensure that `<authentication mode="Windows" />`

I can see that you've already decorated your method with a `[Authorize]` attribute which should trigger an authentication challenge (HTTP 401) when the method is accessed. Now you should be able to access the identity of your end user through the `User.Identity` property of your ApiController class.

Comment: "If you have control over the thread then you can work around this" - could you explain a little more what you mean by this?

Comment: Sure. On the 'main' thread you call 
  var userToken = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Token;
Then you start a new thread and pass this token to the other thread (for example by using a ParameterizedThreadStart delegate) and there you execute
  WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(userToken);

With that being said, if you don't *need* the HTTP requests to be asynchronous, I'd highly recommend you just use either of the synchronous alternatives I mentioned above.

Comment: Will impersonation work if B and C are on different servers? I thought that impersonation would only work for local resources, not remote?

Comment: Absolutely. I spent many years working on a software product which supports this kind of double-hop windows authentication through impersonation.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the help. I am trying to use the RestSharp package:   var userToken = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Token;
WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(userToken);
client.Authenticator = new NtlmAuthenticator();   With impersonation on, it is sending an anonymous request, with imperosnation off, it still makes the request as the app pool. Any ideas?

Comment: I successfully created a proof-of-concept solution with one MVC intranet app and another Web API app, using RestSharp to make windows authenticated calls from one to the other. I have updated my answer to outline the steps involved.

Comment: Turns out it was working but not in Chrome. Once I switched to IE, impersonation worked as expected. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: I have since found out that I can get HttpClient working by changing a couple of config settings as detailed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308938/unable-to-authenticate-to-asp-net-web-api-service-with-httpclient/10311823#10311823

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to access service which is hosted on windows authentication then do following.

```
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
```

If you want to use applications default credentials which must have access on hosted service server

```
request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

*or* user below to pass the credentials manually

```
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Username", "Password", "Domain");
```

Answer (score 0):

The key issue with double hop is delegation of user credential to second call. I want to elaborate a little bit about it. C1 = client browser , S1 = First Server , S2 = Second Server.

Suppose our complete system support window authentication. When user access S1 from browser , its default window credential pass to server S1, but when S1 make a call to S2 , by default it don't pass credential to S2.

Resolution :

1. We must enable window authentication/ impersonation  on both machines.
2. WE need to enable delegation between server so that S1 can trust to S2 and will pass credential to S2.

You can find some useful details at below links :
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/farukcelik/archive/2008/01/02/how-to-set-up-a-kerberos-authentication-scenario-with-sql-server-linked-servers.aspx

https://sqlbadboy.wordpress.com/2013/10/11/the-kerberos-double-hop-problem/