# Can I make HttpWebRequest include windows credentials without waiting for a 401 challenge?

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, httpwebrequest

My app communicates with an internal web API that requires authentication.

When I send the request I get the 401 challenge as expected, the handshake occurs, the authenticated request is re-sent and everything continues fine.

However, I **know** that the auth is required. Why do I have to wait for the challenge? Can I force the request to send the credentials in the **first** request?

My request generation is like this:

```
   private static HttpWebRequest BuildRequest(string url, string methodType)
   {
       var request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
       request.PreAuthenticate = true;
       request.AuthenticationLevel = AuthenticationLevel.MutualAuthRequested;
       request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
       request.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
       request.ContentType = CONTENT_TYPE;
       request.Method = methodType;
       request.UserAgent = BuildUserAgent();
       return request;
   }
```

Even with this code, the auth header isn't included in the initial request.

I know how to include the auth info with basic.... what I want to do is to use Windows Auth of the user executing the app (so I can't store the password in a config file).

**UPDATE** I also tried using a `HttpClient` and its own `.Credentials` property with the same result: no auth header is added to the initial request.

The *only* way I could get the auth header in was to hack it in manually using *basic* authentication (which won't fly for this use-case)

Comment: would this question help you achieve your goal?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316172/httpclient-windows-auth-pass-logged-in-user-of-consumer-to-service

Comment: @tezromania I refactored to make my request using an `HttpClient` as in that link but it still does not include any authorization info in the first request.

Comment: Why do I have to wait for the challenge? The response type for Windows authentication in IIS is also HTTP 401 Challenge.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ntlm is a challenge/response based authentication protocol. You need to make the first request so that the server can issue the challenge then in the subsequent request the client sends the response to the challenge. The server then verifies this response with the domain controller by giving it the challenge and the response that the client sent.
Without knowing the challenge you can't send the response which is why 2 requests are needed.

Basic authentication is password based so you can short circuit this by sending the credentials with the first request but in my experience this can be a problem for some servers to handle.

More details available here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378749(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I accepted this as the answer because it points out that the issue isn't that the credentials aren't embedded, but that there **are no credentials to embed**... The authentication relies upon the challenge.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not 100% sure, but I suspect that there is no way around this; it's simply the way `HttpWebRequest` works.

In the [online .NET source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com), function `DoSubmitRequestProcessing` which is [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/HttpWebRequest.cs#aa9fbe606425aa21#references), you can see this comment just after the start of the function, line 1731:

```
        // We have a response of some sort, see if we need to resubmit
        // it do to authentication, redirection or something
        // else, then handle clearing out state and draining out old response.
```

A little further down (line 1795) (some lines removed for brevity)

```
if (resubmit)
{   
   if (CacheProtocol != null && _HttpResponse != null) CacheProtocol.Reset();
   ClearRequestForResubmit(ntlmFollowupRequest);
   ...
}
```

And in `ClearRequestForResubmit` line 5891:

```
// We're uploading and need to resubmit for Authentication or Redirect.
```

and then (Line 5923):

```
// The second NTLM request is required to use the same connection, don't close it
     if (ntlmFollowupRequest) {....}
```

To my (*admittedly n00bish*) eyes these comments seem to indicate that the developers decided to follow the "standard" challenge-response protocol for NTML/Kerberos and not include any way of sending authentication headers up-front.

Comment: +1 While this is a good answer, I accepted a different answer which links to the MSDN page explaining how hashes are transferred and, thus, why the information cannot be provided in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Setting PreAuthenticate is what you want, which you are doing.  The very first request will still do the handshake but for subsequent requests it will automatically send the credentials (based on the URL being used).  You can read up on it here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.preauthenticate(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.preauthenticate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: No it does not prevent the initial handshake. That `.PreAuthenticate=true` only sends the auth by default *after* authentication has taken place. The `401` is still returned from the initial request.... which is what I said in the question and precisely what I **don't** want to do.

Comment: Right, that's what I'm saying.  AFAIK, there's no way to prevent the initial handshake.