# Connect from MVC app to WebAPI using app pool account

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication

I'm certain I've done this a dozen times before, and I can't think what's causing this to fail now, but, I have an MVC web app with its app pool running as a domain account. It connects to a WebAPI app on the same domain which has Windows auth enabled.

I'd like to be able to read the MVC app pool account name using `controller.User.Identity.Name` on the WebAPI side, but it's coming back empty. I've tried just about everything, including explicitly setting the MVC app to "connect as specific user".

The MVC app is using `HttpClient` to connect to the API. I've tried passing an `HttpClientHandler` with `UseDefaultCredentials` set to true, but that had no effect.

Connecting to the WebAPI methods from my local machine correctly identifies my domain account. Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by adding the `BackConnectionHostNames` key mentioned here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10311823/2179408

It wasn't necessary for me to make the `legacyImpersonationPolicy` and `alwaysFlowImpersonationPolicy` aspnet.config changes though.

The 401 responses I was receiving threw me off and led me to believe it was an IIS authentication issue.