# Passing Credentials works for WebRequest but not for HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, http, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to pass credentials back to a web service using HttpClient.
However, I keep getting an Unauthorized request.
However, when I try using a WebRequest it authenticates?

HttpClient:

```
        var handler = new NativeMessageHandler
        {
            UseDefaultCredentials = true,
            Credentials = credential
        };
        var client = new HttpClient(handler);
        var content = _httpClientHelper.Serialize(data);
        var response = await _client.PostAsync($"{_baseurl}/api/foos/List", content);
```

WebRequest:

```
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        try
        {
            var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
            {
                ViewTitle = "New",
                PageCount = 60
            });

            var content = _httpClientHelper.Serialize(data);

            using (var client = new WebClient { UseDefaultCredentials = true, Credentials = credentials })
            {

                client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                client.UploadData("$"{baseurl}/api/foos/List", "POST", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content));
            }
```

I cannot figure out why one works and the other does not.
Any help or insight on this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If you're providing credentials, then shouldn't you be setting `UseDefaultCredentials = false`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308938/unable-to-authenticate-to-asp-net-web-api-service-with-httpclient) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212116/how-to-get-httpclient-to-pass-credentials-along-with-the-request#16018906) this behavior of HttpClient could be because of how  HttpClientHandler is implemented.

> "[..] the StartRequest method is executed in new thread with the credentials of the asp.net process (not the credentials of the impersonated user) [..]"

You might be seeing the difference in behavior of HttpClient and WebClient because

> "HttpClient creates new threads
>   via the Task Factory.  WebClient on the other hand, runs synchronously
>   on the same thread thereby forwarding its
>   credentials (i.e. the credentials of the impersonated user) ."