# WebRequest Works Locally, but Not When Published

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I have run into a snag while building a web client that makes use of a RESTful web service using Integrated Windows Authentication.

When I run the client locally (as myself), it works fine, and I see my user id in the IIS logs.  But, when I run it remotely, no credentials are passed (i.e. I do not see my user id in the IIS logs), and I get an error that

> "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

Both the local and published client call the same service.  Also note that the IIS logs show two entries (one without a username and one with a username) when I run it locally.  When I run in from the published location, there are still two entries, but neither shows the username.

Below is the code I am using to make the call:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["positionServicePath"] + "?positionNumberSearch=" + searchString);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        request.PreAuthenticate = false;

        CredentialCache cc = new CredentialCache();
        cc.Add(
            new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["positionServicePath"]),
            "Negotiate",
            CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials);
        request.Credentials = cc;

        // Get the Response
        using (var response = request.GetResponse()){
            var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

            // Convert the response to objects from Json
            var resultList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<PositionModel>>(reader.ReadToEnd());

            // Return an empty list, if no data was retrieved
            return resultList != null ? resultList.ToList() : new List<PositionModel>();
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only way I have been able to get any results is by explicitly passing in a username and password using Basic authentication.  Is this truly the only way to pass credentials to an ASP.NET WebApi service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this issue was the same for the answer to the following Stack Overflow post: [Unable to authenticate to ASP.NET Web Api service with HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308938/unable-to-authenticate-to-asp-net-web-api-service-with-httpclient).

Thank you to those who took the time to look this over!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create IIS user permitted to your project.

Follow this [Anonymous Access](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000010773)

**Second Option:**
Try to enabled `anonymous access` in Authentication Methods in Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS).

```
Step:
1. Open your IIS.
2. In IIS Group:
3. open or select Authentication:
4. Select Anonymous Authentication:
5. On the Left Side select Enabled.
```

Good Luck!

Comment: I have actually set up permissions in IIS on the web service to allow the service account being used to run the AppPool for the consuming site.  But, it doesn't work.

Comment: Additionally, we don't want to allow Anonymous authentication, because the service returns personnel data.