# HTTP request is unauthorized by trying to retrieve data from a soap service

Tags: c#, soap, asp.net-core-2.2

When I try to retrieve data from a BC365 soap service in my asp.net core 2.2 controller, I get the following error:

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme
>   'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was
>   'Negotiate'.

**Funny thing is:**
If **I debug the project locally, it works as intended with the following code**:

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
binding.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
var endpointAddress = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(this.soapBaseUrl + "Page/WEB_Item");
var itemPortClient = new WEB_Item_PortClient(binding, endpointAddress);
itemPortClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = this.soapUserName;
itemPortClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = this.soapPassword;
return itemPortClient;
```

But whenever I publish it on IIS, it's not working as intended (I tried already on a remote and the local machine).
I have followed the instructions on https://stackify.com/how-to-deploy-asp-net-core-to-iis/ to deploy my asp.net core application.

My Infrastructure's project .csproj-file's content looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">    
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>    
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Duplex" Version="4.5.3"/>
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="4.5.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp" Version="4.5.3"/>
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Security" Version="4.5.3" />
  </ItemGroup>    
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\BakWebshop.Core\BakWebshop.Core.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>    
  <ItemGroup>
    <WCFMetadata Include="Connected Services" />
  </ItemGroup>    
</Project>
```

If anyone has some idea of what might be amiss or what I could check, I am kind of stuck here at the moment. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was related to different user that was used to start the soap request, using the 2.2 .net core. The request was made with manually defined credentials, but somehow they have not been taken into account when firing the request by the framework.

Running from VS2019, the local user was used and able to connect (was allowed on the soap endpoint).

Running on IIS with application pool using the application pool identity was not working, since somehow not the specified user credentials for the soap request have been used but the ApplicationPoolIdentity - that was not granted access to the soap endpoint.

Workaround was to use a user-defined account for the iis pool.
Looks related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/10311823 and [How to get HttpClient to pass credentials along with the request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212116/how-to-get-httpclient-to-pass-credentials-along-with-the-request)